# What is the scientific name of this plant that is possibly called ogre ears?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I already did a reverse image search and came up with "ogre ears" as a name for this plant. However, this name is associated with other plants: *Crassula argentea* and *Crassula ovata*. What is the scientific name of this plant?

Thanks

[image: Picture]

Comment: plant identification I believe falls under gardening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (lovely) succulent is *Crassula ovata* variety "Gollum", known also as "gollum jade" or "finger jade".  Search for the name and you'll find lots of commercial sources.  One informative source is [here](https://worldofsucculents.com/crassula-ovata-gollum-gollum-jade-trumpet-jade-hobbits-pipe-jade/).

Comment: Okay thanks. Looks like Wikipedia has pictures of other varieties mixed in with this one.

Comment: You are welcome.  Any plant of horticultural interest can be tough to track down if there are lots of varieties.